# How to Check DataSet Tables that contain the same ID?

Tags: c#

My Question is i have one dataset which contains four the tables,now i want to check id (like suppose in table there is one column empID)of second table is available in first table 
or not ,if id is available then i want to remove that id(complete row),similarly third table id will check in first table then second table
and third table is available on any of these table then again that id will be remove from that table. and same process will be repeat for remaining table.

For Exp:

```
BusinessClass.IsProcessedData = DataAccess.getDTHotelInfoIsProcessData();

BusinessClass.IsProcessedData.Tables[0].TableName = "TableOne";
BusinessClass.IsProcessedData.Tables[1].TableName = "TableTwo";
BusinessClass.IsProcessedData.Tables[2].TableName = "TableThree";
BusinessClass.IsProcessedData.Tables[3].TableName = "TableFour";
```

Now suppose tableTwo table has 10 rows and each row will check with tableTwo Rows and if it found same id 
in both table then that id will remove from tableTwo of Dataset. and same process is for all table.
hear i am using c#.Thank You

Comment: Tables[0].Rows[*foundrow*].Delete()

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 foreach(dataset ds in yourmaindataset)
    {
          if(yourmaindataset.contains(ds))
           //TODO:
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using a Dictionary or some sort of key-value pairing, but if you have to do it this way with tables, then something like this would work but would not be efficient:

```
foreach(DataRow row1 in Tables[0].Rows)
{
   foreach(DataRow row2 in Tables[1].Rows)
   {
      If(row2["empID"] == row1["empID"])
      {
           row2.Delete();
      }
   }
}
```

And here is a way you could it with nvp for all tables:

```
Hashtable hTable = new Hashtable();

foreach(Table table in Tables)
{
   foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
   {
      if (hTable.Contains(row["empID"]))
         row.Delete();
      else
         hTable.Add(row["empID"], string.Empty); 
   }
}
```

Comment: It's helpful, or is it what you needed? Are you all set?